# Swift, check if array has value at index

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

```
var cellHeights: [CGFloat] = [CGFloat]()

if let height = self.cellHeights[index] as? CGFloat {
    self.cellHeights[index] = cell.frame.size.height
} else {
    self.cellHeights.append(cell.frame.size.height)
}
```

I need to check whether an element at a specified index exists. However the above code does not work, I get the build error:

> Conditional downcast from CGFloat to CGFloat always succeeds

I also tried with:

```
if let height = self.cellHeights[index] {}
```

but this also failed:

```
Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cellHeights` is an array containing non-optional `CGFloat`. So any of its elements cannot be nil, as such if the index exists, the element on that index is a `CGFloat`.

What you are trying to do is something that is possible only if you create an **array of optionals**:

```
var cellHeights: [CGFloat?] = [CGFloat?]()
```

and in that case the optional binding should be used as follows:

```
if let height = cellHeights[index] {
    cellHeights[index] = cell.frame.size.height
} else {
    cellHeights.append(cell.frame.size.height)
}
```

I suggest you to read again about [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496)